# ubuntu 14.04 running slow on bootup and online

Tags: 14.04, performance, cpu

My apologizes right off is I do not know much about computers.  My laptop crashed and was replaced by my sons college desktop computer that he built.  we had a problem with windows XP on it and solution was to download Ubuntu (version 12.10 at the time and has since been upgraded to 14.04).  computer was running very fast at first but is now running very slow.  under system settings - detail shows. . .

```
Ubuntu   14.04 LTS
memory    2.0 GiB
processor AMD Athlon (tm) 64 processor 3800t
Graphics  Gallium 0.4 on AMD RV770
OS Type   32 bit
disk      244.8 GB
```

went online about this subject and post to another person suggested checking available RAM.  said to open terminal and type `free -mt` and this showed . . .

```
           total    used    free    shared    buffer    cached
mem         2015    1897     117       58      206        920

-/+ buffers cache    770    1244

swap        2045       0    2045

total       4061     1904   2156
```

the only programs I added was Firefox and Google chrome. so why is the system running so slow.  it takes a long time for booting up initially and online when at first it was very quick.  much faster than windows XP was.  FYI, windows XP is no longer on the system as far as I know.  its been progressively slower.  can't say how long Ubuntu has been on system but 12.10 was what I started with.  please help.  thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. 2GB of RAM is probably not enough these days unless you run a lightweight desktop environment such as LXDE. Even then Chrome will quickly eat up all your RAM with only a few tabs open, especially with "app" type sites like gmail that use a lot of javascript. You will probably have to reinstall with the 64-bit version if you want to utilise more than 3GB RAM though.
2. A solid state drive (SSD) will greatly enhance your system's performance and is probably easier to find than compatible RAM.

   You can use it in addition to the current internal disk and [migrate Ubuntu](/q/40372/175814) onto the new drive without re-installation. My tip would be to keep your personal files in the `/home` directory on the rotational disk though, since they have far less impact on the system performance and SSD storage is more expensive (also see [What are the pros and cons of having a separate home partition?](/q/142695/175814) and the [Ubuntu Help on moving the home directory](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving)).

A freshly formatted filesystem will always run faster as files can be laid down in sequential blocks but as time goes on and files are re-written, fragmentation occurs so the disk has to seek to other areas of the platter.

Comment: +1 for 1. and 2. As for fragmentation: that is usually a non-issue with modern file systems – especially ext4. Even after years of heavy use my system partitions only suffer from 1–3 % fragmentation which is not worth worrying about.

Answer (score 0):

Waddles already made [worthwhile suggestions](/a/741427/175814) for possible hardware upgrades to relieve likely performance bottlenecks on your system.

From a software choice and operating system configuration side I recommend to

- [enable zswap](/q/361320/175814) to alleviate the main memory shortage,
- [install additional, proprietary device drivers](/q/47506/175814) for the graphics adapter to make better use of it's graphics acceleration features,
- look into [How can I improve Ubuntu overall system performance?](/q/2194/175814) for generic ideas and system tunables – not all answers and suggestions there are worthwhile any longer in general or in your particular case.